# Водимая информация в TextBox

Tags: c#

1. Если в TextBox`е числа, то я пишу`textBox2.Clear();` Но все равно остается последний введенный символ. Например, если я введу "ывфпа", то останется "а".
2. Как мне поставить ограничение на вводимое количество цифр в textbox. Потому что если я превышу 32 767, то программа рухнет.

Comment: 1) textBox2.Text = String.Empty

Проблема осталась.

Comment: Мистика или вы где-то в коде сами добовляете последний символ.

Comment: http://pastie.org/4585142

Comment: А в чем смысл NumPad? Я вроде бы не с них числа ввожу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1) textBox2.Text = String.Empty
2) textBox2.MaxLength = int.MaxValue;
```

Используйте для этого [элемент управления NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/729xt55s.aspx)

```
private bool _number = false;

private void textBox2_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _number = false;

        if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9) // вводим число
            if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9) // или число на цифровой клавиатуре
                if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back) // нельзя вводить пробелы
                    _number = true;

        label1.Text = (_number) ? "Только цифры!" : "эмпти";

        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
            _number = true;    
    }

private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_number) // если не число то 
            e.Handled = true; // отменяем ввод
    }
```